# My Windows Scheduled tasks do not run

Tags: virtual-machines

I am looking into the Task scheduler in VM, where I have set with Oracle database RMAN daily backup and shutting the instance before its night auto-shutting mode.

[image]

But I don't know whether or not those scheduled tasks work daily. I don't think it is triggered automatically by the Windows scheduler. I've been monitoring these scheduled tasks for past 2 weeks, but seeing no backup and shutdown logs generated by those tasks. I've set it under NT / SYSTEM and administrator credentials. As a result, it keeps databases to be crushed because azure VM shut down during off-hours.

Comment: What do you see under the History section (Eventlog) for that scheduled task?  Have you checked the various logs under `Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/`?  If you scroll to the right on that screen what does it show for last run time, or last result.  What happens if you try right clicking on the task and selecting 'Run'?

Comment: There is progress!! I've checked every logs under Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/ and it shows for last run time at 10 pm with the rman backup scheduled task. If I try right clicking on the task and selecting 'Run', it shows 'running...' but never end.

Answer (score 1):

Good new is that I found history logs under the Windows / Security log section. So I've sent them to the cloud VM administrator.
[Scheduled Task 1]
    Creator Process Name:   C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
    Process Command Line:   C:\windows\system32\OpenWith.exe "F:\app\oracle\admin\cdbcloud\SQL\shutdown_cdb.sql"

[Scheduled Task 2]
    Creator Process Name:   C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
    Process Command Line:   C:\windows\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe /c "F:\app\oracle\admin\cdbcloud\SQL\rmanbackup19c.cmd"

Token Elevation Type indicates the type of token that was assigned to the new process in accordance with User Account Control policy.

The limited token is used when User Account Control is enabled, **the application does not require administrative privilege, and the user does not choose to start the program using Run as administrator.**

Thanks, Zoredache!